# Unable to use UndertowServletWebServerFactory to limit MAX_ENTITY_SIZE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, undertow

Using Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE. I am trying to limit request sizes that Undertow accepts. Would like to have a limit for all types, POSTs, PUTs, multipart, non-multipart etc. There's `UndertowOptions.MAX_ENTITY_SIZE` that I think I should be able to use. I have added:

```
@Configuration
public class UndertowConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public UndertowServletWebServerFactory undertowServletWebServerFactory() {
        UndertowServletWebServerFactory factory = new UndertowServletWebServerFactory();

        factory.addBuilderCustomizers((UndertowBuilderCustomizer) builder -> {
            builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.MAX_ENTITY_SIZE, 100L);
        });

        return factory;
    }
}
```

But this does not work in practice. I am testing by sending requests to my REST @Controller, but request size does not seem to have a limit.

Also when I debug, `io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.getMaxEntitySize()` returns 52428800. So it looks like my configuration is not sticking.

Also tried a bit differently

```
@Configuration
public class UndertowConfiguration implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<UndertowServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(UndertowServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addBuilderCustomizers((UndertowBuilderCustomizer) builder -> {
            builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.MAX_ENTITY_SIZE, 100L);
        });
    }
}
```

which was maybe closer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-programmatic-embedded-container-customization example, but the results were the same.

Also tried application.property `server.undertow.max-http-post-size=100` or `server.undertow.max-http-post-size=1KB` but that one did not do anything either.

**EDIT:** 
Did a small minimal application to replicate the problem: https://github.com/jansu76/gs-spring-boot/tree/undertow-testing/complete

It is a fork from helloworld spring application from https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

I have

- changed config to use Undertow instead of Tomcat
- set application property to limit max post size: `server.undertow.max-http-post-size=10` https://github.com/jansu76/gs-spring-boot/blob/undertow-testing/complete/src/main/resources/application.properties#L1
- used UndertowServletWebServerFactory to set port to 9090 and also limit post size with `UndertowOptions.MAX_ENTITY_SIZE`: https://github.com/jansu76/gs-spring-boot/blob/undertow-testing/complete/src/main/java/hello/UndertowConfiguration.java

To test:

```
cd complete
./gradlew build
java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
cd src/test/resources/
./test-post.sh
```

Script should do a large POST request to the application, which should be limited by Undertow max post size config. But it is not.

It seems UndertowServletWebServerFactory sets port to 9090 but UndertowOptions.MAX_ENTITY_SIZE = 100 has no effect. `server.undertow.max-http-post-size=10` sets some max entity size values for some time, but those are overwritten in `io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest:181` which overwrites maxEntitySize value from 10 to 10485760.

Comment: Created a spring-boot issue about it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18555 - there is a suggested workaround. Going to test it soon.

Comment: Tested the workaround (setting spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size), it works.